# Why am I losing every output value from my loop except for the last one?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am using list comprehension to loop through two unique list, my code seems to be working but when I check my final data frame, it looks like I only have output for one of the values in my first list. Does anyone know why I am losing all of my loop output except the final values?
I should be seeing five unique geographies from the geography column but I'm only seeing one.
thanks!

```
# Starting time before Loop:
t1 = time.time()

# Create Unique Lists of Geography and Product:
geo_list = list(data5['Geography'].unique())
prod_list = list(data5['Product'].unique())

# Use List Comprehension to Loop Through Dataframe based on Geography and Product:
[(g,p) for g in geo_list for p in prod_list]
new_df = data5[(data5['Geography']==g) & (data5['Product']==p)]
new_df['pn'] = new_df['Price']-new_df['Price'].shift(-1)
new_df['price_d'] = np.divide((new_df['Price']+new_df['Price'].shift(1)),2)
new_df['dn'] = new_df['Unit_Sales']-new_df['Unit_Sales'].shift(-1)
new_df['dd'] = np.divide((new_df['Unit_Sales']+new_df['Unit_Sales'].shift(1)),2)
new_df['Delta_Demand'] = np.divide(new_df['dn'].values,new_df['dd'].values)*100
new_df['Delta_Price'] = np.divide(new_df['pn'].values,new_df['price_d'].values)*100
new_df['ped'] = np.divide(new_df['Delta_Demand'].values,new_df['Delta_Price'].values)

# Keep only columns we need:        
new_df = new_df[['Geography', 'Product', 'Price', 'Unit_Sales', 'ped']]
unmatch = data5[(data5.Geography.isin(new_df.Geography)) & (~data5.Product.isin(new_df.Product)) & (~data5.Price.isin(new_df.Price)) & (~data5.Unit_Sales.isin(new_df.Unit_Sales))]
        
# Concat together:
df_final = pd.concat([new_df, unmatch],ignore_index=True)
t2 = time.time()
# Time taken by Loop:
df_final['Geography'].unique()
array(["Kroger Corp w/ Roundy's-RMA - Groc"], dtype=object)
#print("Time taken by Loop: %.6f" %(t2 - t1))
```

Comment: You're not assigning the result of the list comprehension anywhere.

Comment: You're not looping through the list comprehension. So `g` and `p` just have their last values.

Comment: What you probably want is an ordinary loop: `for g, p in zip(geo_list, prod_list):`

Comment: Or `for g, p in itertools.product(geo_list, prod_list):`

Comment: You need a pair of loops, as it appears you want the combination of all geo and prod.

Comment: @Barmar, there is different lengths of the lists. The geo_list has a length of 5 and prod_list has a length of 40. That is because within different geography's we can sell the same products. Products is from the prod_list.

Comment: @AlexNavarro Right, that's why `itertools.product` is correct.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried for g, p in itertools.product(geo_list, prod_list): but I am still getting only one geography returning in my final data frame.

Comment: You need to create the dataframe before the loop and add to it each time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar how do I add to it each time through the loop? Appending?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a pandas programmer so I don't know the specifics.